# How do you create a simple non-persistent server in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, http

As part of a school assignment, I am trying to write a simple server that handles only non-persistent connections.

I am using Java.

From what I've read so far, `HTTP` is by default persistent, and Sockets/ServerSockets in Java  are the same way.

How do I implement `non-persistent` sockets?

Comment: By `persistent`, do you mean can survive the server shutting down?

Comment: I mean persistent in this context - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: We can not reach your teachers mind, but what he likely wants you to do is write a server which accepts a connection, sends the reply and then closes the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-persistent here most propably means that a client's request is served via an (accepted) socket which will **not** be re-used for any subsequent requests by the same client. (Please see here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection#Use_in_web_browsers for a nice picture.)

So just let the server do the following:

1. Create the listening socket.
2. Bind the listening socket to a local interface's address:port
3. Let the socket listen.
4. Wait to accept a client's incoming connection on the listening socket.
5. Read the client's request from the accepted socket and parse it.
6. Create the response and send it back to the client via the accepted socket.
7. Finally shutdown and close the previously accepted socket.
8. Start over at 4.

Comment: Do you mean parsing all HTTP headers and encodings and whatever HTTP also incurs? Non-persistent sockets are really a hell.

Comment: You need to parse each header of each incoming request in any case, independently of whether it's a persistent or non-persistent connection.

Comment: For persistent, I can use existing HTTP server. Or, wait, do you mean that we should always start at the socket level and never use existing HTTP technologies?

Comment: The advantage of a persistent connection is that there are fewer calls to `accept()` and `shutdown()`/`close()`. On application-protocol level (http here) there is **no** difference. Referring the steps I listed above you would start over after 6. going back to 5.. Parsing request-header and creating response-header are part of 5. and 6. Please note the updates on points 5. and 6. in my anser.